# Traversing an object with each in Jade lang

Tags: javascript, pug

I have the following CodePen here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWGqXy

```
          // v.tenants is an object
          p #{v.tenants}

          ul
            // why can't I traverse it here?
            each a in v.tenants
              li
```

What I am trying to achieve is to traverse the `v.tenants` object but instead I'm getting a JS error stating "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". How can I correct the error and traverse `v.tenants`?

Comment: Because, not all floors have this key. Only ground. You need to iterate tenants only if key exists

Comment: Sergey, thank you very much for your reply! Now what I've added tenants to all the floors, indeed it works just fine! It appears I need to find if that key first exists before doing anything else :)